# Using Twitter typeahead to make search bar work

Tags: php, search, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead, twitter-typeahead

I am using Twitter typeahead to make my search bar work but coming across some issues.

**Purpose of the search bar**:

The search bar will be used to search usernames of users who are registered to the site.

**Approach**:

In the `head` of `home.php`:

```
<script src="typeahead.min.js"></script>
```

`header.php` (which is included in `home.php`):

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search user" name="typeahead">

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
        name: 'typeahead',
        remote:'search.php?key=%QUERY',
        limit : 10
    });
});
    </script>
```

`search.php`:

```
<?php
include("connect.php");

    $key=$_GET['key'];
    $array = array();
    $query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE '%{$key}%'");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
      $array[] = $row['username'];
    }

    echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

**Current results:**

If with the above code, on `home.php` I try to search for the user `Alice`, who is a real user (I am not clicking on search by the way, I am simply typing her name in the search bar. I expect, if Alice is a real user, her name will show up in the drop down). But if I do search for her the URL changes.

Summary:
If I type Alice (dont press search), nothing happens. I expect a drop down to appear as Alice is a real username.

If I type Alice and DO click the search button, the URL changes to:

```
http://localhost/home.php?typeahead=Alice
```

**How I expect it to work:**
[image]

**Edit**:

Another approach I tried in `header.php`:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search user" name="typeahead">

<?php  
// getting all usernames from db
        $statement = mysqli_prepare ($connect, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE account_type ='user'");
        mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
        $usernames = array();
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($statement);
        while($get_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result)){
            $usernames[]       = $get_data['username'];
        }
        mysqli_stmt_close($statement);     
    ?>

<script>
    var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
  return function findMatches(q, cb) {
    var matches, substringRegex;

    // an array that will be populated with substring matches
    matches = [];

    // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
    substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

    $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
      if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
        matches.push(str);
      }
    });

    cb(matches);
  };
};

var username = <?php echo json_encode($usernames); ?>;

$('#the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 1
},
{
  name: 'usernames',
  source: substringMatcher(username)
});
    </script>
```

The following approach has been adopted from [Github](https://gist.github.com/jharding/9458744#file-the-basics-js).

With this approach I still do not get a drop down list which displays any matching names.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your declaration for the typeahead. A typeahead can't use a remote source directly.  It has to either be provided through a function or through a bloodhound object.

If you check out the [documentation for typeahead](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#options), you will see that there is no setting for `remote`.

The [examples page](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) has some good ideas as a place to start as well.

I like to use a [bloodhound object](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md), but it does complicate thing a bit.

Create the bloodhound object:

```
var taSource = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('Value'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  identify: function(obj) {
    return obj.Value;
  },
  remote: todos
});
```

I separate out my `remote` object hash:

```
var todos = {
  url: urlRoot + '/todos',
  prepare: function(query, settings) {
    settings.url += '?q=' + query;
    return settings;
  },
  filter: function(data) {
    return $.map(data, function(obj) {
        console.log(obj)
        return {
        Id: obj.id,
        Value: obj.title
      };
    });
  }
};
```

So the typeahead declaration looks like this:

```
$('#search-input').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 3
}, {
  name: 'myMatches',
  source: taSource,
  display: 'Value'
});
```

In this case I'm searching against the `title` in the JSON, which is mapped back to `Value` in the object passed to typeahead.  The JSON actually looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "fugiat veniam minus",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 4,
    "title": "et porro tempora",
    "completed": true
  }...
```

Here is [a fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/whipdancer/vrcg4ofg/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I have been trying to implement your approach, and I still get the same results. But I think I am not placing the code in the correct files. Where do I create the `bloodhound` object? I have currently have created the `bloodhound` object, `remote`  and declaration in `header.php`, which is where the search bar is created. Also, please see my edit. I have tried another approach using the examples provided by you.

Comment: All the code in this example depends on document.ready.  I assume that the `<script>` tags in `header.php` are output to the browser.  In that case, all this code could go inside `$(document).ready(function(){});`